# TaffyDB not querying record

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, taffydb

When trying to query a variety of records in the database, using the below array, TaffyDB will not lookup the record correctly. 
Syntactically, it appears to be sound and should query and return the value of the record, but I assume I'm missing some fatal point.

```js
$(".cat").each(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  var db = ($this.data("category")).toString()
  var fn = window[db];
  if (typeof fn === "function") fn().each(function(r){
    var parts = ["cpu", "mobo", "ram", "gpu", "sc", "hdd", "ssd", "psu", "case", "cooler", "os"];
    var pmup = "";
    for(i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
      var part = r.parts[i];
      console.log(part) // returns: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
 part = r[parts[i]];
```

instead of

```
part = r.parts[i]
```

solves the syntax error.